# Whats the meaning of 'They have let us know that they would like to move forward'?

Tags: meaning

"They have let us know that they would like to move forward "
Does it mean that they will let us know if they are going to move forward or not or does it mean they told us that they decided to move forward ?

Comment: This question will be better suited at English Language Learners. http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

"They have let us know" means "They have told us".

The whole phrase means something like "They have decided to go ahead with it." -- but the wording contains some doubt, either intentional or subconscious.  Have they definitely told the speakers of a firm decision, or have they merely indicated a preference?  Are they committed to the entire project, or just to the next step forward?  If these questions matter to you, I think you would be justified in pressing for a firmer commitment.